# sql query to find a price, for item amount between the range

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am having a table with fields

```
item_no  item_amount_from  item_amount_to price
101        200                  300        10
101        300                  400         20
101        400                  500         30
101        500                  null        40
```

i want to make a query which can retrieve price if item amounts are in between (item_amount_from) to
(item_amount_to) range please let me know how should i wit the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at something like this.

I will note though that you are missing the opening row. Something like 101, null, 200, 5

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        item_no INT,
        item_amount_from FLOAT,
        item_amount_to FLOAT,
        price FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 101,200,300,10 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 101,300,400,20 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 101,400,500,30 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 101,500,null,40

DECLARE @Amount FLOAT,
        @ItemNO INT

SELECT  @Amount = 510,
        @ItemNO = 101

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
WHERE   item_no = @ItemNO
AND     (
                ((item_amount_from <= @Amount AND item_amount_to > @Amount))
            OR  (@Amount >= item_amount_from AND item_amount_to IS NULL)
            OR  (@Amount <= item_amount_to AND item_amount_from IS NULL)
        )
```

Comment: But it is in terms of stored procedure, cant i have some direct query

Comment: what is the cncept of isNull in this

Comment: the IS NULLS would be to check for the unbounded rows (500 up), so if the amount is 510.

Comment: If you're into the whole brevity thing, the query could read, assuming some appropriate defaults,  AND @amount between isnull(item_amount_from, 0) and isnull(item_amount_to, 999999)